# Getting the key from a HTML element name using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, forms

I have a HTML form that uses array names for some elements so that I can easily read through the values later in PHP, regardless of how many elements I end up with. For example:

```
<select name="brand[1]">...</select>
```

In the jQuery .change() event for these elements I'd like to find what the key is, i.e. '1' in this example. Obviously I could just split the name attribute and see what I'm left with but is there a more proper way? I feel like there should be but I can't seem to find a tidy solution.

Thanks.

Comment: `.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1]` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name'),
    var key = name.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];

    alert(key);
});
```

Comment: Ohh, I hadn't thought of using Regex. Seems to not be working so well though... .match() appears to be returning only one value and this contains the [ and ] part too. I've also tried /(\[(\d+)\])/ and /\[([0-9]+)\]/ but the result is the same - [1] is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up by using the `g` flag. I updated by answer by removing that, should work now.

Comment: Ah, that works, thanks! I'm confused though... Doesn't the g modifier just prevent the match from ending after the first find? Actually now I've written that I suppose it makes sense for this to effect the result =). I'll wake up soon!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a html tag to identify the key and get it in JQuery. You would get something like this:

```
<select data-key="1" name="brand[1]">...</select>

<script>
 $('select').change(function(){

    var theKey = $(this).data("key");
 });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're going to use custom attributes, at least use the proper `data-` ones.

Comment: This is probably the tidiest answer I'm going to get, but unfortunately I'm working on an older project that isn't HTML5 and custom attributes would break w3 compliance with this one :-(.

Comment: It's not a big problem. This isn't 100% correct/valid usage in HTML4, but normally it doesn't cause problems either.